# WAS server does not read white spaces

Tags: java

WAS server does not read white spaces (`\n` `\r` `\t` etc) while writing file from `FileInputStream` to server response output stream. how can I add new line.
I used below code:

```
HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
File file = new File("fileName");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);
inputStream.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
response.flushBuffer();
```

There are new lines in the file but while viewing it there is only one space on browser. I also tried to explicitly add `\n`,`\r`,`\t` using `out.write('\n')` but it didn't work. 
This works fine on weblogic.

Comment: Is this HTML? If you use "view source" in the browser, what do you see? It doesn't help that as far as I can see you're not setting a content type or encoding on the response...

Comment: in view source it is as the file (with spaces there), while inspecting element  it is html  and body having the file content.  weblogic automatically adds <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre> before the content, while on WAS it behaves as simple HTML and trims spaces. I do not want to add content type because file can be in any format. Do I need to make response as HTML?

Comment: Well you shouldn't expect the code you've provided to do anything but serve the file it's given - in other words, it's behaving perfectly. It's not clear what kind of files you're serving or what you expect to happen to them, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks Jon, my problem get solved by making response as html I used response.setContentType("text/html"); and write the content beetween html tag out.print("<html><body>"); and using <pre/> tag, that made white spaces visible.

Comment: That's not going to be helpful if the file isn't text though, for example. If you know it *is* text, you should set the content type to text/plain. Then there's the issue of the text encoding...